# Showing my raster map on mobile app (iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, gis

I'd like to show a map on my app and handling some events within it. I'm also need to load a background raster map to it (dwg format, which is the AutoCAD format for raster, but it doesn't really matter, since it can be converted to any other known format), doesn't matter if the file is local or remote.

I know very well how to id on desktop, but which options I have on mobile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have [TileOverlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay) on Android and [Tile Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/tiles) on iOS, which can both use remote and local data source.